# Sum up items in a Flex Card

Tags: omnistudio, vlocity, omniscript, data-raptor

I am quite newb when it comes to Omnistudio, just getting the grips of it.

I have two flex cards, parent and child.

The parent is just a collapsible toggle, and shows/hides child card.

Child card is a bunch of quote line items and their prices.

Ideally I'd like to show a total for all the items fetched in the quote line items. I cannot think of a solution here other than have another child flex card which takes the {records} param from other child card and then somehow Sums up what is in the Invoice_Amount_Inc_VAT__c field.

How do I do such sum? I've tried a Data raptor formula but cannot for the life of me make it work to sum up a given JSON.

Here is the example
[image]

I am using parent child because next phase of this will be implementation of an action button against each element, such as remove, which will delete that quote line item.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.
vio